# Question about the effects of cardinality changing on the model's training

Tags: machine-learning, python, categorical-encoding, pandas

I'm analyzing a dataset that contains a feature 'street_name' with 5980 unique values. I used the LeaveOneOutEncoder class for encoding, but I noticed that the cardinality reduced a lot. There are now 340 unique values. In another feature called 'name' the cardinality increased. Before there were 309 unique values and after encoding 1239 nunque.
So, I would like to know if this could be a problem when training the models. What are the effects of this cardinality changing on the model's training